# css spacing issues- overlap between posts?

Tags: css, position, padding, margin

My intention is to have the post_entry level with the headline. I've noticed that some entries do this while others are shifted up or down seemingly random amounts. What is causing this? How do I fix/prevent it?

Site- http://whskytngfxtrt.com

[image]
<sub>(the slope of the red lines show the problem)</sub>

Thank you.

Comment: Your HTML is a mess. You should not be wrapping the entire content of a post, images, links and all, in a P tag. Consider DIVs or LIs to wrap posts. Also in HTML, IDs are supposed to unique, yet you have id="headline" throughout your document. You don't need a FIX, you need a re-write.

Comment: You have one big DIV.post_entry containing all your entries... wrap them all separately.

Comment: how do i wrap them separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it has something to do with the margin-top you put on everything by hitting #main .post_entry and p, but unless you clean up your HTML (as Diodeus and Didier Ghys recommended: put everything into separate divs) it's impossible to say for sure. Sorry!

In your CSS, I noticed something else in this part:

```
#main .post_entry p {
font-size: 80%;
font-weight: normal;
line-height: 150%;
margin-left: 230px;
margin-bottom: 25px;
margin-top: -82px;
overflow: hidden;
width: 403px;
margin-top: -82px;
}
```

As you see, there is two margin tops of -82.

Comment: thank you for pointing this out- i guess i overlooked it. removing the second margin-top helped, but didn't completely fix the issue.